# Why there is a pom.xml for all jars in mave repository

Tags: maven

In the maven repository, there is a pom.xml corresponding to every jar. What is the use of that pom.xml.
How important is that pom.xml and will the execution work without that pom.xml ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pom.xml contains all the metadata about the jar.  This is what makes Maven useful.

Answer (score 1):

Each of those jars is a project (somewhere) that was built using Maven - hence the need for a pom. Also, the pom describes all the [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for any jar that your project needs. Those files are important, and your project cannot build without them.